# Can we deploy from higher environment(sandbox) to lower environment using change set

Tags: deployment, deployment-api

Can we deploy from higher environment(sandbox) to lower environment(sandbox) ?

for example preprod to dev sandbox using change set ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can deploy from any environment to any other environment. 
For that you need to connect the two sandbox from deployment setting.

Follow below steps:

Go to your lower environment -> Setup -> Deployment Setting -> Edit in the name of higher environment and then select "Allow inbound changes" and save it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, but there is a deployment model to design before setting up change sets.  A good practice is to create a staging environment that allows you to do a test deployment before deploying to production (like a full copy sandbox / prod replica).
Once you find the model that fits for you just setup the change set connection between  the orgs like @salesforce Developer says.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can deploy from higher env. (pre-prod/prod) to lower env.(QA/Dev).

You can see in Setup of every org, there are 2 options:
Outbound Change Set - Create change set here to deploy to any Target org.
Inbound Change Set - Any incoming change set from any Source org.

It's just they should already have connection established between them.
Without connection, you won't be able to upload/deploy.